# Excel Formula for fixed percentage

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating an excel document for a team comparing % of team salary player was paid (column a) vs. % of team production on the court (column b) in excel.

I subtract production-salary paid and get one number (column c) .

I am looking for an excel formula that will calculate new salary at a fixed differential so I can create a chart of what we should pay each person to get them to a +1.5 differential, so I can plug and play with different players.

Comment: Can you share some sample data so the requirement is clearer? Thanks!

Comment: Player A contributes 15.5% to her team's success based on her combined stats. Player A takes up 5% of her team's total salary. Player A has a +10.5 difference between her contribution to teams success and salary. She would be a player that is undervalued.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would write:

in C1: `"Differential"`

In C2: `=B2-A2`

Then drag the formula down from C2 to fill however many rows you wish.